# is there a way i can make componentDidMount work in react native file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to do a splashscreen for an app but using reacts componentDidMount in the typescript related file given by starter react native project returns an error.
This is the `app.js` code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, StatusBar, Button, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Header, LearnMoreLinks, Colors, DebugInstructions, ReloadInstructions, } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import Login from './src/components/login/login';
import Register from './src/components/register/register';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import componentdidmount from './src/components/componentdidmount';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
    componentDidMount(){
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Login />
        </>
    );
};
```

the splash screen shows fine but doesnt let the login page come into view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't use `componentDidMount` inside a functional component use class component instead or use `useEffect`.

**Class Component**

```
import { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }

  render() {
    return <Login />
  }
}
```

**Functional Component**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => SplashScreen.hide());
  return <Login />;
};
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: I tried `useEffect()` and i was hit with a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable useEffect` but it works just fine with the class component

Comment: @web_walkerX you have to import it from react as ```import { useEffect } from "react";```

Comment: @web_walkerX If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use componentDidMount inside a functional component use class component instead or use useEffect.

Class Component

> componentDidMount() {
> SplashScreen.hide();
> }

Functional Component

> useEffect(() => {SplashScreen.hide()});